# How to avoid duplicate entries in a reminder app?

Tags: swift, xcode, calendar

I'm currently working on a reminder-type app for school. You plug in a year, month, day, hour, and minute, then add those values into arrays. I would like to make it so that if those exact same values are going to be inputed again, it won't be added to the array. Ex: I input 25/12/2019 at 6:30. If I input that exact same time again, it won't add all the values to the array, but if I input 25/12/2019 at 6:31, it will add all the values to the array.

`monthDuplicate` is a duplicate array of `remindMonth`, which has all the values for the months. Anything with 'remind' in front of it is an array for their respective values. Anything with 'Set!' at the end of it is the text field for its respective value. `isProperTime()` is just a function that runs the rest of the code (the code that adds stuff to the arrays)

I'm pretty bad at explaining this, and pretty new to programming so if anyone needs any clarification for my rambling I'd happily oblige. Any help would be very appreciated.

```swift
while monthDuplicate.contains(monthSet!) {
    if let index = remindMonth.firstIndex(of:monthSet!) {
        print(remindMonth)
        if remindYear[index] == yearSet! && remindDay[index] == daySet! && remindHour[index] == hourSet! && remindMinute[index] == minuteSet! {
            reminderError.text = "Reminder already exists"
            monthDuplicate.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            isProperTime()
        }
    }
}
isProperTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I haven't tested this, but this will probably work.

Here you take your total array count. Since you are adding values to all arrays(year,month,day,hour,min) , their count would be the same. So we are just taking the count of 'remindYear' array.

Now we simply check each position of each array index to see if your date exists with for-loop.

(*There might be a better,faster way than this*)

```
let arrayCount = remindYear.count
for var i in(0..<arrayCount)
{
 if remindYear[i] == yearSet! && remindDay[i] == daySet! && 
    remindHour[i] == hourSet! && remindMinute[i] == minuteSet! 
  {
   reminderError.text = "Reminder already exists"
   monthDuplicate.remove(at: i)
  }
 else 
  {
    isProperTime()
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating individual arrays for days, months, and years is excessive and wasteful. Why not just store the input dates as `Dates()` types, and store them in an array, and then convert the array into a sorted `Set` which orders the dates but removes duplicates and retains `Date()` type.

```
let datesArray = ["Wed, 25 Dec 2019 06:30", "Wed, 25 Dec 2019 06:31", "Wed, 25 Dec 2019 06:31", "Wed, 25 Dec 2019 06:32"]
var noDuplicates = [Date]()

for dates in datesArray{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

     if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dates){

    noDuplicates.append(date)
    }

}



let orderedDates = Array(Set(noDuplicates).sorted())

output: [2019-12-25 06:30:00 +0000, 2019-12-25 06:31:00 +0000, 2019-12-25 06:32:00 +0000]
```

or put them into an NSOrderedSet which also retains order and removes duplicates but will change the array type from `Dates()` to `Any()` type.

```
let orderedDates = NSOrderedSet(array: noDuplicates).array
output: [2019-12-25 06:30:00 +0000, 2019-12-25 06:31:00 +0000, 2019-12-25 06:32:00 +0000]
```